# Batch script to send e-mail if files do not exist

Tags: batch-file

I want a batch script which checks for a file(*.txt) for last 7 days in a folder. If the file are there, will ignore and exits. If there is no files in last 7 days, sent a alert email to xxx@xxx.xxx

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: I would go for a powershell script, and if that's not possible, a vbs script.

Answer (score 0):

1. Finding files modified in the last 7 days:

   ```
   forfiles /D -7 /M *.txt
   ```
2. Find a program that can send e-mails. [Rob van der Woude](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/email.php#Links) has links to a few. Then it just becomes:

   ```
   forfiles /D -7 /M *.txt /C "send_mail ..."
   ```